# Calculate CRC for File(content)

Tags: c++, c++20, checksum, crc

I tried to create a program to create a crc sum for a file, based on its content. My intention is to compare this with a older value to see if content changed. I work on Linux (Debian).
I tried this code below and it seems to work:

```cpp
FileInfo fi;
fi.strPath=strPath_;
std::ifstream input(fi.strPath, 
std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> bytes(
   (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
   (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
input.close();
unsigned long long ullNumber = 0;
for( auto &bytes:bytes )
    {
        ullNumber += (unsigned long long)bytes;
    }
cout << "Number: "<<ullNumber<<"\n";
fi.ulHash=ullNumber;
mvctFileInfoNew.push_back(fi);
```

My Question is: Is this way "ok" to use or bad (unfortunatly Iam not so experienced) and I would like to get some opinion from someone more experienced to imrove my skills.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the title of a question on SO.

Comment: Bad. Adding up the bytes is not a good check. Use a CRC routine from an existing library like zlib.

Comment: Thanks for the device @Mark Adler, by any Chance you maybe wäre of a Native libary in C++17 like zlib?

Comment: zlib is written in C, and so will link easily to your C++ code.

Comment: Ah ok thanks @Mark Adler I will look into it. Thanks for your time and guidance.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is, the value does not change.

It's not supposed to. The [`filesystem::hash_value` is a hash of the *path* to the file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/hash_value), not the *contents* of the file. If you want to compute a CRC of the contents of a file, you're going to have to read those contents and apply a CRC algorithm to them.

Comment: Can you provide me some educational hint if i can do so with fstream or something else?

Comment: I postet an Update for my code @Nicol Bolas , (I edited the main so the code is readable).